# Running Python code on RStudio (via Flexdashboard)

Tags: python, r, rstudio, dashboard

I have been using Flexdashboard recently through R Studio and I can run it using pure R code (to build dashboards). However, I am also trying to run Python code on Flexdashboard. Is there a way to get it working ?

Essentially, I'm trying to build a dashboard which outputs visuals through a mix of R and Python codes.

Answer (score 0):

you can use PythonInR package.
https://github.com/cran/PythonInR

you need to install python packages manually from cmd.
like

```
pip install newspaper
```

in R

```
library(PythonInR)
pyConnect('C:\\Users\\yourname\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\python.exe')

xpyrun <- paste('article = Article("', http_adress, '")', sep="")
pyExec(code = xpyrun)

pyImport("Article", from = "newspaper")
myart <- pyGet("article.download()")
```